# Trying to learn C, but I'm running into weird bugs (to me at least)

Tags: c, char, scanf

I'm trying to learn C on my own, I have some previous experience in Matlab and Python. I'm trying to create a simple guessing game where you give a number, the computer guesses a number and you have to tell it if it's higher or lower. I've written some code, but it just doesn't work (try inputting 30, for example). The code is ugly, but I'm just trying to understand what's going on.

I've tried writing it using the case statement, but same results there.

Also, what is going on when you answer the y/n question with yy? The numbers go way up all of a sudden?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(void) {
    int a;
    int i = 1;
    int b = 50;
    int temp;
    int last = 0;
    char ans = ' ';
    printf("Enter value for computer to guess (0-100): ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    while (a - b) {
        printf("Is the number larger than %i (y/n): ", b);
        scanf("%s", &ans);
        if (ans == 'y') {
            temp = b;
            b = b + ((b + last) / 2);
            last = temp;
        } else {
            temp = b;
            b = b - ((b + last) / 2);
            last = temp;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("Your number was: %i. Number of guesses was: %i \n", b, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char ans = ' '; ... scanf("%s",&ans);` --> `scanf(" %c",&ans);`

Comment: If you enter `yy` then the first `y` is read by the first `scanf`, and then next time you come around to `scanf` the second `y` is read.  (scanf means "extract character(s) from input buffer and wait only if the buffer is empty", not "wait for input")

Comment: Note that you should use <> and not "" to include non-user defined library (e.g : #include <stdio.h>)

Comment: Note that you also are leaving the enter key un-handled.  You will want to use " %s" (note the leading space) to ensure that the whitespace is consumed.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer `%s` already consumes leading whitespace

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &ans)` would fix the overflow issue and ignore the extra spaces such as `\n`, but would not fix the `yy` issue.

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
 scanf("%s",&ans);
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you're overrunning the allocated memory.

To use `%s` format specifier, you'll need an array as the argument (pointer to the first element of the array, to be specific).

However, in your case, changing

```
 scanf("%s",&ans);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&ans);  // note the space
```

is likely to solve the issue. Optionally, to handle the *extra* input, (like `yyy`), you can consider *clearing* the input buffer after reading each input, like

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

or likewise.

Comment: `while (getchar() != '\n');` is a potential infinite loop if end of file occurs before the `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the computer to binary search for the answer and get there efficiently.  You'll need to keep track of the upper and lower boundaries where you're searching.  Try something like this;

```
int main(void){
    int a;
    int i = 1;
    int b = 50;
    int lower = 0;
    int upper = 100;
    char ans[256] = {0};
    printf("Enter value for computer to guess (0-100): ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    while (a-b) {
      printf("Is the number larger than %i (y/n): ",b);
      scanf("%s",ans);
      if (ans[0] == 'y') {
        lower = b;
        b = b + ((upper-lower)/2);
        printf("Last: %d - %d\n",lower, upper);
      }
      else {
        upper = b;
        b = b - ((upper-lower)/2);
        printf("Last: %d - %d\n",lower, upper);
      }
      i++;
    }
    printf("Your number was: %i. Number of guesses was: %i \n",b,i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem.

```
char ans = ' ';
...
scanf("%s",&ans);
```

`ans` has only a single byte of memory, but you've asked `scanf` for a whole string.  So it dutifully stuffs the whole string into the single byte of `ans`.  Since this includes a null byte, even the input `y` or `n` will write an extra byte.  `yy` writes three bytes.

This causes `ans` to *silently* overflow its memory wrecking havoc on adjacent variables.  This is why `yy` messes with things, you're putting 3 bytes (2 characters plus a null byte) into 1 allocated byte overflowing by 2 bytes.  It overwrites `last` with the character `y` which is the number `121`.  You can see this with a few debugging `printf`s.

```
    printf("b = %d, last = %d\n", b, last);
    printf("Is the number larger than %i (y/n): ",b);
    scanf("%s",&ans);
    printf("b = %d, last = %d\n", b, last);

Enter value for computer to guess (0-100): 30
b = 50, last = 0
Is the number larger than 50 (y/n): yy
b = 50, last = 121
```

---

Instead you want to use `%c` to read a single character.  But that has its own problems, `scanf("%d", &a)` is leaving a newline on STDIN and `scanf("%c", &ans)` will read that newline first.

This is why `scanf` is a problem and should be avoided, it can leave unexpected input in the stream.  There's lots of answers here on SO recommending against `scanf`.  Instead use `fgets` or `getline` to read the whole line and *then* use `sscanf` to read the string.  I prefer `getline` because it handles allocating line memory for you.

Here's a sketch of what to do.

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t linelen = 0;

printf("Enter value for computer to guess (0-100): ");
getline(&line, &linelen, stdin);
sscanf(line, "%d", &a);
printf("You entered %d\n", a);

printf("Is the number larger than %i (y/n): ",b);
getline(&line, &linelen, stdin);
sscanf(line, "%c", &ans);

switch(ans) {
    case 'y':
        ...
        break;
    case 'n':
        ...
        break;
    default:
        printf("I don't understand '%c', try again.\n", ans);
}

free(line);
```